# I want to run the same .Net Core container in Docker Swarm but with different appsettings.json file?

Tags: docker

I want to run the same .Net Core container in Docker Swarm but with different appsettings.json file?

Is there a way to override the default appsettings.json used when running a container?

Win 2019 nodes

Comment: Hint: Mount that file, don't bake it into the image.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to do this mount?  Can you point me to documentation for this?  I have very little experience actually writing this, am more of a post deployment troubleshooter.  Will this be in the compose?

Comment: Also, we use Stack files

Comment: It's in the [Volumes section of the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference). You can mount a directory or just an individual file.